# I have an arraylist with 6 elements and I want to print the first two elements, then third to fourth, and fifth to sixth

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> Numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        Numbers.add("1");
        Numbers.add("2");
        Numbers.add("3");
        Numbers.add("4");
        Numbers.add("5");
        Numbers.add("6");

        System.out.println(Numbers);

        for(int i = 0; i < Numbers.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; Numbers.size() == 2; j++)
            System.out.println(Numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble doing the logic where I have 6 numbers in my arraylist and I want to print each 2 elements then go the next elements by 2. Like to print 1, 2 then 3, 4 then 5, 6.

Comment: Hint: `List` has a `get` method that accepts an `i`ndex. Also, `for` loops aren't limited to `i++`. You can also do `i+=2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Numbers.size(); i+=2){
        System.out.print(Numbers.get(i));
        if(i<Numbers.size()-1) {
            System.out.print(" " + Numbers.get(i+1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Go in steps of 2 `i+=2`.
Then print the first number using `System.out.print()` which will not print a newline.
Then check whether there is a second number to be displayed `if(i<Numbers.size()-1)` and if there is print it separated by a space (or whatever you like).
And then the `System.out.println()` will just print the newline.

Answer (score 1):

Make life easy and use an [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). You don't want to juggle with indexes too much as it obfuscates your code.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = numbers.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next() + "," + (iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : ""));
}
```

Comment: Sure: your answer misses the point. This is clearly homework and your solution is more complicated than it needs to be and probably uses concept OP has no idea about without "having the decency" of explaining them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator to determine when to print a new line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Numbers.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(Numbers.get(i) + (i % 2 == 1 || i == Numbers.size()-1 ? "\n" : ", "));
}
```

For every even index and for the last element in the list, this will print a new line after the element. And for every odd index, a trailing comma would be printed.